# Object created from a list of values

Tags: java, list, object, methods

I am retrieving list of values in 3 different lists like below :

List 1 prints out `a,d,g`
List 2 prints out `b,e,h`
List 3 prints out `c,f,i`

I want the above data to be returned as an `object` which would look something like that :

```
[{
A: a,
B: b,
C:c
},
A: d,
B: e,
C:f
},
A: g,
B: h,
C:i
}]

ArrayList<String> destList = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> resultList = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> statusList = new ArrayList<>();
//adding elements to all the three strings.
    for (int y = 0; y < foo.length() - 1; y++) {
      System.out.println("A"+":"destList.get(y)+",");
      System.out.println("B"+":"+resultList.get(y)+",");
      System.out.println("C"+":"+statusList.get(y));

    }
```

This would retrieve my elements but I am unsure how to make an object out of it. I know my attempt is too rudimentary.
How can I form and return an object like that ?

Thanks,

Comment: Are the size of each lists are same?

Comment: You need to show your attempt.

Comment: Yes. Sizes are same.

Comment: This is very unclear, what's the input? lists, like List<String>, or stuff read sequentially from file/stdin, or something else? Java is strongly typed, but maybe what you're looking for is just a Map?

Comment: Ok. i am editing.

Comment: "I want the above data to be returned as an object which would look something like that" but what you are showing us is an array or list indeed.it is a array or list of objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you need.I have commented the code for your understanding

```
 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.List;

 public class demo {
 public static void main(String[]args){
    List<Integer>list1=new ArrayList<Integer>();
    List<Integer>list2=new ArrayList<Integer>();
    List<Integer>list3=new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ////here add your values to the list,i have not added them.You  first need to add the values to the list
    //then iterate through your list
    //create a list of your own custom class
    List<object>finallist=new ArrayList<object>();
    for (int i=0;i<list1.size();i++){
    finallist.add(newobject(list1.get(i),list2.get(i),list3.get(i)));//use new keyword to instantiate or  create a reference of a new object
    }
    //now your finallist contains your required data
}
  static class object{//create your custom class
  int A,B,C;

  public object(int a, int b, int c) {define a constructor
      A = a;
      B = b;
      C = c;
     }
   }
 }
```

Comment: I am using this inside a method, so if my method is returning a `finallist`, does the my method return type be `List<object>` ?

Comment: @AYa Yeah.Your method return type should be `List<object>`.small `o`.And if this solution worked for you don't forget to accept it

Comment: Thanks. Dude can you also help me with a sample mockito test to such a method ?

Comment: @AYa"Sample mockito test" i didn't get that

Comment: I mean how would we go about writing unit tests for this if we are returning an Object here. Mockito is used for mocking. However, here junit is sufficient I think.

Comment: @AYa Actually i have never done unit tests.I  use java just for  competitive coding not for  development.So i am not much deep into it.sorry